# Шрифты на резиновом шаблоне

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер.
Верстаю резиновый шаблон и возникли неожиданные трудности с шрифтами. А именно, то что все уезжает из-за размером шрифтом при уменьшении экрана.
Вот сам макет - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может можно как-то сделать так, чтобы шрифты уменьшались с размером экрана? Хотя бы чтобы до 1024px все было резиновое, дальше адаптивом сделаю.

Comment: Укажи размеры шрифта в величинах `vw` и `vh`

Answer (score 1):

#### Вариант 1: использование @media

Вы можете добавить новое правило для размера шрифтов через `@media`:

```
@media (max-width 845px) {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

#### Вариант 2: использование единиц vh и vw

Также вы можете задавать размер шрифтов через единицы `vh` и `vw`, которые вычисляются относительно размера `viewport`:

```
font-size: 12vh;
```